# How to set UISearch bar to UiActionSheet in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uiactionsheet, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am just wondering that Is there anyway to set `UISearchBar` or `UISearchDisplayController` to `UIActionSheet` in iOS App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIActionSheet is deprecated, its replacement is UIAlertController. I don't think I'd try putting a UISearchBar on it though.

I'd use a regular UIViewController with modalPresentationStyle set to UIModalPresentationPopover, and then present it as a [popover](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-create-popovers-in-ios-9/) using its [popoverPresentationController property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/popoverPresentationController). This method requires at least iOS 8.